# What is the default datatype for stmt.executeQuery(query)?

Tags: java, jdbc

My oracle table `employee` has different datatype columns. For my purposes, I just need the data of each column as string. So, When I execute the below query, can I assume that `date_of_birth` (date datatype) will be returned as string.

```
...
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");
...
rs.getString("date_of_birth");
...
```

Comment: You can always try it. I'm under the impressions that the underlying drive will complain if data types are not convertible.

Comment: rs.getString() for a non string data type will not work.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja it will work or not depending on JDBC support for it.

Comment: Look at Appendix B (and specifically B.6) of the [JDBC 4.2 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) if conversion to string should be supported (note that some drivers are more lenient than the specification)

Comment: I also suggest you look at the `ResultSetMetaData` to find out how to process a column. That or call `getObject` and infer it from the actual object type returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you [can](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#table2) get data as string using `ResultSet`s getString but it depends on jdbc driver.

But I would use recommended method from that table to retrieve column as it is always supported.

Comment: Technically what is and what isn't supported is defined in appendix B of the JDBC (4.2) specification, but I have to admit it usually depends on the driver. And `getString()` should be supported for `DATE`, `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` as well (it is specced to work for almost all data types).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't assume that.
You have to check your database columns types and use appropriate get methods based on that
e.g. `getString(), getInt(), getDate() etc..`

Comment: Also, it will depend on the support the JDBC driver provides.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot assume this. Most probably `date_of_birth` will be returned as `java.sql.Date` or some other date/time Java type (depending on the DB type, really).

Comment: No. The result of `date_of_birth` will depend on the type specified in database. And you can recover it depending on the support of your JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, I said the same "depending on the DB type, really"

Answer (score 0):

The datatype is probably java.sql.Timestamp, and yes if you call getString on it, you will get something, it will call toString on the timestamp value, you may not like the format of the date.